# Dynamic reconfiguration in a loop

Tags: c++, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am want to use the dynamic confegiration in a while loop: like the following:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "My_pck/Control.h"
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/server.h>
#include <My_pck/comm_dynConfig.h>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<int16_t> Values(9,0);

void paramsCallback(My_pck::comm_dynConfig &config, uint32_t level)
{
   Values[0] << (int)config.value_1 ;
   Values[1] << (int)config.value_2 ;
}

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
   ros::init(argc, argv, "node");
   ros::NodeHandle n;
   ros::Publisher pub  = n.advertise<My_pck::Control>("topic1", 1000);
   ros::Rate loop_rate(50);
    while (ros::ok())
    {
    dynamic_reconfigure::Server<My_pck::comm_dynConfig> param_server;
    dynamic_reconfigure::Server<My_pck::comm_dynConfig>::CallbackType param_callback_type;
    param_callback_type = boost::bind(&paramsCallback,  _1, _2);
    param_server.setCallback(param_callback_type);
    
   My_pck::Control Message;
    
    Message.values  = Values;
    pub.publish(Message);
    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
   }
  return 0;
}
```

The Configuration file has the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
PACKAGE = "My_pck"
from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator_catkin import *
gen = ParameterGenerator() 
#gen.add(name, type,Reconfiguration level, Description, default, min, max)
gen.add("value_1"  , double_t ,0, "1"  , 444 , 0.0, 1024)
gen.add("value_2", double_t ,0, "2", 454 , 0.0, 1024)
exit(gen.generate(PACKAGE, "My_pck", "comm_dyn"))
```

In the wiki, the dynamic reconfiguration is done in the main without while loop. In my case, I used a while loop and it is hard to change the values where they return to the their position when using the scroller and the actual values are always zeros. Any suggistions ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196180/dynamic-reconfiguration-in-a-loop/) by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2014-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rather than creating and destroying the dynamic reconfigure server on each loop iteration, you should create it outside of your while loop.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2014-10-29**:
I did that, it helped me to change the data from the scroll easier. but still all the values are zeros...

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-29**:
You're using the bit-shift operator (`<<`) instead of the assignment operator ('=').

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2014-10-29**:
When I used the '=' the value changed to the first one in the scroller and never changed ???

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2014-10-29**:
Yes it worked now  using the "=" but I changed the data type in the cfg file to int_t... THANKS